# Very strange android error when attempting to start emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

After several days, my Android emulator has flat-out died. I have gotten a few issues here and there about it not working and this is the most recent one. The android emulator starts up, then crashes immediately with this screen error:

[image]

Here is the error report from the eclipse console:

```
[2013-05-02 16:55:37 - AndroidTutorials] ------------------------------
[2013-05-02 16:55:37 - AndroidTutorials] Android Launch!
[2013-05-02 16:55:37 - AndroidTutorials] adb is running normally.
[2013-05-02 16:55:37 - AndroidTutorials] Performing com.example.androidtutorials.Splash activity launch
[2013-05-02 16:55:38 - AndroidTutorials] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'nexus7'
[2013-05-02 16:55:38 - AndroidTutorials] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'nexus7'
[2013-05-02 16:55:39 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Requested RAM size of 2048MB is too large for your environment, and is reduced to 1152MB.
[2013-05-02 16:55:40 - AndroidTutorials] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2013-05-02 16:55:40 - AndroidTutorials] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2013-05-02 16:55:40 - Emulator] savevm: unable to load section cpu
[2013-05-02 16:55:40 - Emulator] qemu: hardware error: smc91c111_read: Bad reg 0:c
[2013-05-02 16:55:40 - Emulator] 
[2013-05-02 16:55:40 - Emulator] CPU #0:
[2013-05-02 16:55:40 - Emulator] pc=0x801bbf24 HI=0x000e495a LO=0xc31b7e34 ds 0090 801bbe80 0
[2013-05-02 16:55:40 - Emulator] GPR00: r0 00000000 at 00000000 v0 bf013000 v1 00000010
[2013-05-02 16:55:40 - Emulator] GPR04: a0 00000001 a1 0000000c a2 bf01300c a3 00000000
[2013-05-02 16:55:40 - Emulator] GPR08: t0 0000000c t1 02351200 t2 12005452 t3 00085634
[2013-05-02 16:55:40 - Emulator] GPR12: t4 00000000 t5 00000000 t6 00000019 t7 00000000
[2013-05-02 16:55:40 - Emulator] GPR16: s0 9e86e000 s1 9e839b00 s2 9ea28280 s3 9e86e000
[2013-05-02 16:55:40 - Emulator] GPR20: s4 ffffffff s5 00000014 s6 80357da4 s7 80360000
[2013-05-02 16:55:40 - Emulator] GPR24: t8 00000000 t9 801bbe80 k0 7f9ca7b0 k1 9dcc3fe0
[2013-05-02 16:55:40 - Emulator] GPR28: gp 9dcc2000 sp 9dcc3d10 s8 00157baa ra 8021c4f0
[2013-05-02 16:55:40 - Emulator] CP0 Status  0x10008c01 Cause   0x10800000 EPC    0x2aab2d7c
[2013-05-02 16:55:40 - Emulator]     Config0 0x80000482 Config1 0x9e190c8b LLAddr 0xffffffff
[2013-05-02 16:55:40 - Emulator] 
[2013-05-02 16:55:40 - Emulator] This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
[2013-05-02 16:55:40 - Emulator] Please contact the application's support team for more information.
[2013-05-02 17:03:38 - AndroidTutorials] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.example.androidtutorials.Splash activity launch'!
```

or
http://pastebin.com/Y4RhyPcw
I have also had the issues in the past following hours on how the emulator will not even start, load, or will delete the application I am trying to run.
Thanks to everyone who can help in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

It's looks like you don't have enough free memory to run the emulator.
Try to create another emulator that require less memory.

Comment: I have been using a lot of applications while doing this, but I don't think that has much too do with it. Any-ways I am just going to test applications on my android now, it seems easier and gives more of a idea on what the final product will look like.